# Insert UITableView row without ANY animation

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0]] 
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

When doing this every row after the one I'm inserting slides down. I want them to immediately jump to their new place. I don't want to call `reloadData` since then all my cells would be redrawn.

Is it possible to remove this animation?

Comment: Maybe setting the alpha on the cell works as suggested here. Not sure though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976700/problems-with-animation-when-deleting-the-last-row-of-tableview-ios7

Comment: You never accepted an answer - could you please accept the answer below with all the votes? Works well.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This works for me:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

[self.tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! This is especially useful when inserting/deleting conditionally in viewWillAppear

Comment: `beingUpdates` and `endUpdates` are redundant.

Answer (score 15):

This also works

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths:withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
});
```

Comment: issue here that this stops scrolling for a moment as well.

Comment: This works very well. I highly recommend this method because it is less prone to bugs because you do not need to keep track of a global as @Fotash suggested. For example, if you disable UI animations and then reenable, this might screw up something else if you accidentally do this within a larger block of enabling/disabling

Answer (score 3):

Swift example (from my chat)

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
        messagesTable.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: messages.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .none)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I ran into this same issue and there was no way for me to remove the animation.

Must be a bug with the UITableViewRowAnimationNone animation type since iOS (of any version) does not seem to respect it.

Comment: Ok, so it is something wrong here? At first I thought it had to be two different animations since setting `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` didn't remove it.

Comment: Late to the thread, but UITableViewRowAnimationNone specifies that there is no animation when the cell is inserted. That is, it won't slide in from the sides, top, bottom, or fade. The table itself may animate to rearrange all the cells, however. It's no animation on a particular row, not no animation overall unfortunately.

Comment: The docs for say `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` "The inserted or deleted rows use the default animations.", which is pretty silly. Why not just call it UITableViewRowAnimationDefault?

Answer (score 0):

If you update the UITableView's dataSource and call `[tableView reloadData]` instead of manually inserting the row, the table will refresh without any animation.

Comment: Apologies, just noticed that you stated you don't want to call `-reloadData` on this occasion.