# Insert UITableView row without animation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation, and setting with UITableViewRowAnimationNone. Then i use the the mehod below 
[Insert UITableView row without ANY animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920699/insert-uitableview-row-without-any-animation)

But it causes a flash when reload the tableview. How can i fix the flash?
Thank you。

My demo is want to pull to load more local data and show on the tableview，but the last position is previous contentOffset.So i overwrite the UITableView's setContentSize function.

```
- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
    if (!CGSizeEqualToSize(self.contentSize, CGSizeZero)) {
        if (contentSize.height> self.contentSize.height) {
            CGPoint offset = self.contentOffset;
            offset.y += contentSize.height - self.contentSize.height;
            self.contentOffset = offset;
        }
    }

    [super setContentSize:contentSize];
}
```

When pull to refresh, load the data and refresh tableview:

```
for (long j = 0; j < result.count; j++) {
                NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0];
                [array addObject:index];
            }

            [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
                [_mainTableView beginUpdates];
                [_mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [_mainTableView endUpdates];

            }];
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43752860/edit) you question to show your code.

Comment: if you still have a reloadData() remove it

Comment: If you want to give animation when add row in table use   Insert UITableView row without.

But if you dont want to give animation just use reload tableview.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 i dont have a reloadData. I use insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: @Jignesh Mayani I just want to reload some rows, Not the whole tableview.Thank you.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have post the code. Thanks.

Comment: Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRow` or `heightForRow`?  If not, do so

Comment: is it possible for you to post more of your class, I know you stated you dont use reloadData() here, but i feel like you may have it in your class, my suggestion would be to put a break point on each reloadData() in your class, perform your action and see if one of your breakpoints gets hit

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I have reedit the question and make it more clear. Any help. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulw11 No help when i implemented estimatedHeightForRow.